# How to get the sum of the product of selected column in a data frame?

Tags: r

This is probably very simple but I couldn't think of a solution. 
I have the following data frame, and I want to multiply column y with column z and sum the answer.

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,4,6), z = c(2,3,4))
> df
  x y z
1 1 2 2
2 2 4 3
3 3 6 4
```

The value found should be equal to 40.

Answer (score 1):

`with` would be an option here if we don't want to repeat `df$` or `df[[` to extract the column

```
with(df, sum( y * z))
#[1] 40
```

---

Or `%*%`

```
c(df$y %*% df$z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could use data table. The second row after the comma indicates columns (j). You don't need the spaces, they're just there to show how it works.

```
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(2,4,6), z = c(2,3,4))
#dt i    j      by
a[   , sum(y*z),  ]
```